# How to create different printer profiles for different paper types on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, printing

I am often switching between different types of paper and lanscape/portrait for printing on the same computer on Windows XP. Can I create different profiles for the same printer so I can easily switch between different paper/layout settings?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear what you mean by "different profiles". You can create multiple print queues (Printers) that all refer to the same physical device but have different default settings. I suspect that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple printer queues and give different name to everyone (Like: HP xxxx Color, HP xxxx Black, etc). Finally customize everyone queues by setting proper printing defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the same printer multiple times using the same driver and then configure each printer differently in Windows XP.

Just start the installation process over and over as many times as needed.  From Printers & Faxes click Add Printer, uncheck automatically detect, select the port, select driver.  Be sure to name it something different.  This has worked here for us when setting up users to print color and B&W to the same printer.  In some cases we have 8 instances of the same printer installed on the same machine, but configured differently.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to configure several presets (individualized settings that you can select at print time to change orientation, paper size, etc). Based on the model printer and driver, open the properties/preferences for the printer and see what's available to you.